# How to serialize TAO::unbouded_basic_string_sequence<T> using boost::serialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, corba, boost-serialization

This does not work:

```
    template <class Archive, typename T>
    inline void save(Archive& arch, const TAO::unbounded_basic_string_sequence<T>& varSequence, unsigned int version)
    {
        size_t length = varSequence.length();
        arch & length & make_array(varSequence.get_buffer(), length);
    }

    template <class Archive, typename T>
    void load(Archive& arch, TAO::unbounded_basic_string_sequence<T>& varSequence, unsigned int version)
    {
        size_t length;
        arch & length;

        varSequence.length(length);
        arch & make_array(varSequence.get_buffer(), length);
    }


    template <class Archive, typename T>
    inline void serialize(Archive& arch, TAO::unbounded_basic_string_sequence<T>& varSequence, const unsigned int version)
        {
            split_free(arch, varSequence, version);
        }
```

The compiller says:

```
(..)/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118:9: error: request for member 'serialize' in 't', which is of non-class type 'char'
```

I know that C-style strings are not supported by boost::serialization. Theoretically I could use std::string for save(), but I do not know how to go back from std::string to TAO::unbouded_basic_string_sequence - there's almost no documentation for this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion seems to be that you expected the sequence to contain characters, whereas in reality it contains zero-terminated strings.

From looking at the implementation code (indeed the documentation isn't very helpful) it seems like the Unbounded Basic String Sequence uses the String Traits to know how to operate on the strings.

The traits for `T = char` indicate that the `StringManager_T<T>` class is used to "manage" strings. So, it's a convoluted setup in which the sequence stores raw pointers to "unowned" zero-terminated strings.

However, implied through the trait is that all operations are done via the string_sequence_element proxy that uses the StringManager, and this emulates value-semantics for null-terminated strings. E.g. [assignment is done like](http://www.theaceorb.com/1.3a/doxygen/tao/classTAO__String__Manager.html#a5)

```
00055 {
00056   CORBA::string_free (this->ptr_);
00057   this->ptr_ = CORBA::string_dup (p);
00058   return *this;
00059 }
```

I have no way to test the correct operation of this all, but here's a raw attempt you can try:

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {

    template <typename Archive, typename T>
        inline void save(Archive& ar, TAO::unbounded_basic_string_sequence<T> const& varSequence, unsigned int /*version*/)
        {
            ar & varSequence.length();

            std::basic_string<T> scratch;
            scratch.reserve(256); 

            for (size_t i = 0; i < varSequence.length(); ++i) {
                scratch.assign(varSequence[i]); // assumes zero-terminated
                ar & scratch;
            }
        }

    template <typename Archive, typename T>
        void load(Archive& ar, TAO::unbounded_basic_string_sequence<T>& varSequence, unsigned int /*version*/)
        {
            size_t length;
            ar & length;
            varSequence.length(length);

            std::basic_string<T> scratch;
            scratch.reserve(256); // some sane starting point?

            for (size_t i = 0; i < varSequence.length(); ++i) {
                ar & scratch;
                varSequence[i] = scratch.c_str();
            }
        }

    template <typename Archive, typename T>
        inline void serialize(Archive& ar, TAO::unbounded_basic_string_sequence<T>& varSequence, const unsigned int version)
        {
            split_free(ar, varSequence, version); 
        }

    template <typename Archive>
        inline void serialize(Archive& ar, SequenceOfString& sos, unsigned int /*version*/) {
            ar & base_object<TAO::unbounded_basic_string_sequence<char> >(sos);
        }
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks - one small thing:  save() should obtain object to be serialized by const reference.

Comment: @Siekacz hrm? I have that, right? I compiled the code (I just can't link it because I don't have TAO built)

Comment: Oh, yes - just didn't see the const before & :)

Answer (score 0):

You are taking a route which you shouldn't take at all to my idea. When you are using IDL and generate the type mapping based on that you should use the CORBA (de)serialization that is generated by TAO and use the types as defined by the IDL to C++ mapping, you are now using all kind of internal classes.

At the moment you have your IDL types you can (de)serialize these to a sequence of bytes using the CodecFactory support, see ACE_wrappers/TAO/tests/Codec for example code. Using the CodecFactory you can do this in a portable way that works with any CORBA vendor.

Comment: Then show a doc how to do it - there is nothing on the web. And I need XML or something readable, not binary.

Comment: There is no standardized way to marshal IDL to XML or something readable, only to a binary form which is part of the CORBA specification. As part of DAnCE there is code that is able to read D&C data from XML and convert it to an IDL representation, see ACE_wrappers/TAO/DAnCE/tools/Convert_Plan which can be starting for doing something similar for your types.